# Java DatagramSocket stops responding under heavy network load

Tags: java, sockets, networking, load, timeout

I have a client which needs to listen on a particular port for incoming UDP broadcast messages.  I accomplish this by initializing a DatagramSocket object bound to the port with a setSoTimeout of 1500ms.

```
while (true) {
    try{
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_LEN];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        datagramSocket.receive(packet);

        [handoff packet to internal buffer to await processing]

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException timeout) {
      ...
    } catch [other exceptions]
}
```

It's pretty textbook and everything works just fine; however during a recent network load test I discovered that my application was not receiving certain datagrams, and the problem worsened the more congested the network got.

Digging further I found that the timeout was triggering each time the the .receive() was called - almost as if there was nothing arriving on the port.  **However running Wireshark on the same machine shows that this is not true**, and well-formed packets of expected size and content are arriving as usual. Somehow the datagrams just weren't finding their way to the application layer.

Ramping down the network traffic immediately alleviates this issue, and the Java application is immediately able to receive and process packets as usual.

Can anyone shed some light into what could possibly be the issue here, or what I can do further to troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

UDP flood protection on a software firewall perhaps?

Also, UDP is an unreliable protocol by design.  It could be that the network layer is discarding packets due to load.

Comment: Can this still be the case if wireshark is logging the inbound data just fine?

Hours of Googling turns up just one guy who has the same problem as me - only his triggering conditions are different.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/06a33876-fb45-4bfe-90c2-d27a27e48e3f

Comment: To be honest I don't know.  You could be running foul of drivers, a flakey network card, a funny OS revision, or anything.  Given that yours is load-related and reproducible, and without knowing how Wireshark actually reads the data, I'd bet it's most likely some sort of firewall or throttling solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the packets are arriving at the host they can still be discarded by the host if the socket send buffer is full, which happens when the app can't keep up with the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't often program in Java, so maybe I'm missing something here, but why are you calling `new DatagramSocket` inside the loop?  It seems like that would create a new socket for every datagram, which would quickly exhaust system resources.

Comment: whoops. I blame my pseudocode. The actual code defines the socket once. Thanks for pointing that out anyways.